# Moving the 10 oldest Backups to archive using Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, archive

i looking for an solution using a Batchfile to do the following.
I do every day a backup of my databases in an folder, which named after the day eg.

2013-05-13

. **This is already fine**.

Now the Problem:

At the end of a month i want to combine the oldest 10 folders (including all files) to an archive folder.
All files from the 10 oldest folders should moved to the archive folder. Same files should overwritten (oldest to new) and the folder (now empty) should also removed.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should move the contents of the oldest 10 folders to an archive folder (which should pre-exist), overwriting and keep the latest copies, and remove the folders: but it doesn't expect subdirectories in the backup folders.

After you test it you can schedule the batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "d:\source\folder"
set "c=0"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /od') do (
set /a c=c+1
if !c! LEQ 10 (
     echo "%%a"
     move /y "%%a\*.*" "D:\destination\archive\" >nul
     rd "%%a"
  )
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you. Works fine. Only the Sort direction is the way round. Its move the new to to archive instead the oldest one. Fixed it

Comment: Thanks.  The correct change is to use /od but because your names sort correctly then /on may also work for you.  I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to install [UnixUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) to get `mv`, `tail` and `head` utilities

Then

```
dir /b /AD /OD|tail -n 10 > temp.txt
```

gives you list of 10 newest directories in current one

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (temp.txt) do echo D|mv -f "c:\source\%%i" "c:\destination\%%i" /y >temp.bat
```

creates script moving them somewhere

```
call temp.bat
```

calls it.